# RUBY CSV Gem generating random quotation mark

Tags: ruby, csv

I'm trying to generate a `csv` file from a `SQL query result`.
99% of the time it does work fine, but in some lines (rows) of the CSV file, it does generate a quotation mark at the start and the end of the row.

The problem pictured:
[image]

I've already checked the content of the SQL cells and it is ok.

So I think the problem happens when generating the file.

Here it is the way the file it's been generated.

```
#load query result
dataset = DB[ "select
                        id
                       ,action
              from
                        some_table"]

#generate csv file
CSV.open("#{table}.csv", "wb",:write_headers=> true, :headers => ["id_cliente|""acao"] ) do |csv|
      dataset.each do |dbrow|
        csv << [
                "#{dbrow[:id_cliente]}"
                + "|" +
                "#{dbrow[:acao]}"
                ]
        end
end

new_object = $bucket_response.objects.build("#{table}.csv")
new_object.content = open("#{table}.csv")
new_object.acl = :public_read
new_object.save
```

Is there anyway so solve it or improve the generating process?

Comment: does this only happen on lines with Thayane?

Comment: Actually I looked carefully and I saw there's a break line on its name "Thayane".
Now I got  a new issue.

Comment: yeah, i had a feeling there was a newline after thayane. csv encapsulates multi-line fields in quotes. and because of the issue mentioned in mdesantis' answer, the algorithm thinks the entire row is a single field.

Comment: @eiko You are right. There were a "char(10)" at the string.
Now it works fine.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You must specify the separator instead of passing it as a string:

```
CSV.open("#{table}.csv", "wb", col_sep: '|', ..., headers: ['id_cliente', 'acao']
    ...
    csv << [dbrow[:id_cliente], dbrow[:acao]]
    ...
```

For more infos check the [`CSV`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html) and [`CSV::Row`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV/Row.html) docs

Comment: Don't do `"#{dbrow[:id_cliente]}"`. Just do `dbrow[:id_cliente]`.

Comment: @mdesantis Actually I had an "char(10") inside the string, so it was breaking the cell.
Anyway, your tip improved the speed and the size of the file.
Thanks.